# Skype detects webcam, but it is disabled in calls

Tags: 16.04, skype, webcam

I'm new to Ubuntu as I just installed it yesterday and everything seems to work fine except for Skype video conferencing.

It detects my **front and rear built in camera** just fine as I can see myself in the preview options, but when calling somebody the video option is disabled.

I can also take pictures and videos on cheese. I'm running *Ubuntu 16.04 64bit* on a ThinkPad Helix and Skype 4.3. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Are you sure, the camera is not locked by any other application? Usually some light glows when camera is locked. Check if no light is glowing before using skype.

Comment: Yes, it was not locked, but the below answer solved it for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try reinstalling skype:

```
sudo apt purge skype*
skype_link="https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-$(uname -m|cut -d '_' -f2).deb"
wget -c ${skype_link} -O skype-install.deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: -f install was a good touch! I have to do the same with chrome-browser

Comment: The linked package is very out of date as of July 2017. Here is a link to a newer version: `http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb` . Then `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb` .

Comment: yeah this works, but installs old version 4.3 which is no longer supported.